# EC2 instances of same security group cannot communicate through SQL Server connection

Tags: php, sql-server, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, windows-server

I have 2 EC2 instances with Windows Server OS, one of them (lets call it S1) hosting my PHP code using IIS and the other one (lets call it S2) hosting the Databases using SQL Server. They belong to the same security group.

Pinging each other works but connecting to the DB of S2 through S1 gives me a timeout error.

This is the error I get:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => 258
            [code] => 258
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.

            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The wait operation timed out.

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => HYT00
            [SQLSTATE] => HYT00
            [1] => 0
            [code] => 0
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 08001
            [SQLSTATE] => 08001
            [1] => 258
            [code] => 258
            [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
            [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
        )

)
```

Some things I have tried:

- The code for connecting is definitely correct as it is the same code being used by some of my other servers that can connect to each other fine. But just in case, it is PHP code and it is as follows:

```
$conn = array(
   'UID' => USERNAME,
   'PWD' => PASSWORD,
   'Database' => DATABASE,
);
if (!$conn_id = sqlsrv_connect(HOSTNAME, $conn)) {
   // exit blah blah
}
```

Mind you, this is a multi-tenant application that initially connects to a master DB and then to the appropriate client's DB. Connecting to the master DB works fine (which btw is hosted in a server of a different security group). It is only this specific S2 client's DB that gives me a timeout error.

- I have set up rules for both of them using both their private and public/elastic IPs in the security group. I even tried opening traffic to all tcp connections but it still doesn't work.
- I have disabled windows firewall in both of the servers.
- SQL Server Authentication is enabled and the port 1433 is open for SQL Server connections.
- I have configured SQL Server in S2 to allow remote connections through Server properties -> Connections.
- I run this command in both of them through the CMD `netsh http show iplisten`. I noticed in that in S1, the list returned is not empty, meaning only specific IPS are allowed. However, I tried clearing the list or adding S2's IPs to it. Neither works.
- I tried doing the opposite, i.e. connecting to an SQL Server DB of S1 through S2, and it also gives me a timeout error.

EDIT: One thing I haven't mentioned above is that the application in S1 that is failing to connect to S2's DB is using a secondary IP that I set up (this IP is used by other applications with no problems). I have setup rules for both this secondary IP and its assocciated elastic IP in the security group. Don't know if this is important but I mentioned it just in case.

Comment: 1. Install telnet and verify that the sql server port is open. 2. Make sure SQL Server Authentication is enabled in your SQL Server.

Comment: Ok, just verified that port 1433 is open using telnet. Also verified that SQL Server Authentication is enabled through Server Properties -> Security.

Comment: What exact error message do you get? Are you seeing a login attempt in the SQL Server logs? Disabling Windows Firewall sounds like a pretty bad idea. Is this a default instance or a named instance? If default, are you sure the port is correct? If it's a named instance, you either need to have SQL Server Browser service running and you don't use a fixed static port, or you fix a static port *not* on 1433. `netsh http show iplisten` is not relevant here, try `netstat -ano | findstr "1433"` on the SQL Server machine

Comment: The port is definitely correct. The instance is the default instance (MSSQLSERVER). Just in case however, I opened the SQL Server browser and it still doesn't work.
````netstat -ano | findstr "1433"```` Returns the following:
TCP    0.0.0.0:1433           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       748
 TCP    [::]:1433              [::]:0                 LISTENING       748

Comment: Does your connection string include `HOSTNAME,1433` or `tcp:HOSTNAME,1433`? If it is using an instance name like `HOSTNAME\MSSQLSERVER` then you need to also allow udp/1434 for instance name resolution via the SQL Browser service.

Comment: The connection string is tcp:HOSTNAME,1433. It is also a default instance, not a named instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just because two Amazon EC2 instances "belong to the same security group" doesn't mean that they can communicate with each other.

Security Groups are **applied individually to each resource**. So, if two instances are associated with the same security group and you want them to communicate, you would need a rule in the security group that **allows inbound connections from the security group itself**.

A better way to configure it would be:

- Put a security group on the app server (`App-SG`), permitting inbound connections for your web server, and
- Put a security group on the database serve (`DB-SG`) that permits inbound connections from `App-SG` on port 1433

This way, `DB-SG` permits inbound connections from any EC2 instances associated with `App-SG`.

Comment: Hey John, thank you for the response. I tried adding a rule in the Security Group as follows: – 
Type: All TCP
Protocol: TCP
Range: 0 - 65535
Source: {{the SG id}}
I still get connection time out though. I am starting to believe that this is not a security group problem.